# Problems with Parallel build using MSBuild

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio, serialization, msbuild, parallels

We've tried to run next command:

```
MSBuild.exe ..\src\YaccConstructor.WithoutTests.sln /t:Build /m:8 /v:q /p:Optimize="True" /p:DebugSymbols="True" /p:Configuration="Release" /logger:Fake.MsBuildLogger+TeamCityLogger,"C:\Users\User\Documents\Project\recursive-ascent\tools\Build.Tools\Fake\FakeLib.dll" /logger:Fake.MsBuildLogger+ErrorLogger,"C:\Users\User\Documents\Project\recursive-ascent\tools\Build.Tools\Fake\FakeLib.dll"
```

After that we've got the next exception:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB4166: Child node "6" exited prematurely. Shutting down. Diagnostic information may be found in files in the temporary files directory named MSBuild_*.failure.txt.
```

In the MSBuild_*.failure.txt is the next information:

```
    System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost' in Assembly 'Microsoft.Build, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodePacketTranslator.NodePacketWriteTranslator.TranslateDotNet[T](T& value)
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.LogMessagePacketBase.WriteToStream(INodePacketTranslator translator)
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.LogMessagePacketBase.Translate(INodePacketTranslator translator)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeEndpointOutOfProcBase.PacketPumpProc()
```

We've see all of the follow information:

[Compiler Issue in Windows 7: A generic error occurred in GDI+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017731/compiler-issue-in-windows-7-a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi)

[error MSB4166: Child node exited prematurely. Shutting down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916687/error-msb4166-child-node-exited-prematurely-shutting-down)

[MSBUILD fails with "The process cannot access the file xxxxx because it is being used by another process." when maxcpucount is greater than 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838779/msbuild-fails-with-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-xxxxx-because-it-is-being)

And nothing helped.

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly calling the build with MsBuild 4.0 to rule out version 12.0

Try ruling out the custom loggers by omitting the /logger switches.

Try ruling out parallel builds by commenting out the /M switch.

Try piping the diagnostic output to a separate file and see if you can get more fidelity on the error.

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 ..\src\YaccConstructor.WithoutTests.sln /t:Build /m /v:q /p:Optimize="True";DebugSymbols="True";Configuration="Release" /fl1 /flp1:Verbosity=diag;logfile=msbuild_diag.log
```